# Random variable defined on the Lebesgue probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

There is a random variable X defined on the Lebesgue probability space whose cumulative distribution function is F.
We can find X(w) knowing that:

$X(ω)=\inf\{x∈R:F(x)>ω\}$.

1) how do we prove that for the uniform random variable (in the Lebesgue probability space) on $ [a,b] $, :

$X(ω)=a + (b-a)ω $

2) for a discrete random variable (f.i the Bernoulli distribution) how does this formula applies ?

3) A similar problem: how to prove that Y(w) = 1 - w is a random variable, and how to give its distribution? 
My guess is that we use $$P(Y \le x) := P(\omega | Y(\omega) \le x)$$

$$ Y(w)\le x $$
$$\iff   w\ge 1-x$$
 Then we have : $$ P(\omega | Y(\omega) \le x)= (1-x)  1 _{x\ge0}\ $$
Am i on the right path?